# How to style a PHP record with HTML and CSS

Tags: php, styles

this is my first time i ask a question here, i hope you guys can help me out with this hopefully. I have a php projet where i have a database connection, i am using bootstrap twitter as css framework. The database is dutch language, it doesn't effect the code in this case.

Problem:The PHP file does not allow me to use html between the php code under:

*// Query add record: I want to style these lines of code.*

This is the code, i cant display images because i don't have a 10 reputation..:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

    <?php

    //stap 4) De resultaten naar het scherm schrijven
    echo "<h3>Stap 4 Inhoud database:</h3>";
    while ($rij = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    ?>

    <div class="container-fluid well col-md-12">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">

     <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=50" alt="80x80" class="img-rounded pull-left" style="width:80px; heigth:80px;">

        <?php

        // Query add record:I want to style these lines of code
        echo "Les{$rij['doc_id']} <br /> <hr> :
       {$rij['vaknaam']}<br /> {$rij['omschrijving']}<br />"; 

        ?>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried some styling in the php file but i really have no clue how to do this in the following code:

```
<?php
// Query add record:I want to style these lines of code
echo "Les{$rij['doc_id']} <br /> <hr> :
{$rij['vaknaam']}<br /> {$rij['omschrijving']}<br />"; 
?>
```

Hope you guys can help me out, Thanks in advance!
Paul

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to style this output.  You can put `<span>` and `<div>` tags or any other html tags with css classes or inline css that you want

```
echo "<span class=\"someclass\">Les{$rij['doc_id']} <br /> <hr> :
   {$rij['vaknaam']}<br /> {$rij['omschrijving']}<br /></span>";
```

or

```
echo "<span style=\"background-color:#dcdcdc;\">Les{$rij['doc_id']} <br /> <hr> :
   {$rij['vaknaam']}<br /> {$rij['omschrijving']}<br /></span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of [bootstraps' in-built styling](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) (e.g. [tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)) if you would like to see a visual difference in how your data is outputted.

To keep your code readable, I'd suggest using single quotes to prevent unnecessary escaping of double quotes.

E.g.

```
// Query add record:I want to style these lines of code
echo 'Les ' . $rij['doc_id'] . '<br/> <hr> : ' . $rij['vaknaam'] . '<br />' . $rij['omschrijving'] . '<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean markup! but can you show me an example of boostrap table styling with this query record?